# Is there a simple example how to integrate static website (plain HTML + javascript) with AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I must admit I am struggling understanding AWS Cognito docs and therefor I seek some very simple example (starter) of how to use it in a web app. First, I must say Amplify is not for me as I do not plan to use any of the frameworks supported by it (most examples, videos and tutorials are for React, not my cup of tea unfortunately).
What I look for:

- how to check in the landing page if the request was sent by authorized user (already logged in)? (this is something I did not understand at all)
- which API will provide necessary tokens when the user wants to log in? I tried to call buil-in UI, but seem not to be able to test it with a development version of my app ("a plain HTML page") hosted on a localhost - the login always fails.
- how is the web app supposed to store tokens, is it in request/response headers, in localStorage or anything else?

Or at least some pointers to very simple examples, not involving specialized frameworks, building tools etc. I would like to understand how to call he basic APIs and the rest will come later. So far I was unable to find any suitable "bare bones" examples or tutorials.